# using NPM to install cryptoJS

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio, npm, cryptojs

I'm trying to install cryptoJS  at my visual studio 2015.
my npm version is: 4.5.0
my node version is: v6.10.2
I've done:
1. install via nuGet Node.js
2. install via nuGet npm

3.
    npm init --force
which gave the output:

```
npm : npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm init --force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm WARN using ... you are doing.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Wrote to \myProjectPath\package.json:

{
"name": "myProjectName",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"crypto": "^0.0.3",
"node.js": "^0.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
```

}

I don't think that output is valid.
When I try to install cryptoJS :

```
npm install crypto-js
```

the output is:

```
npm : npm WARN MyProjectName@1.0.0 No description
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install crypto-js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm WARN MyProjectName@1.0.0 No description:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

npm
WARN
MyProjectName@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

how can i fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should probably test if it is working or not. Please create a new file called *crypto.js* with the following code:

```
var sha256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
console.log(sha256("Hello"));
```

Then, run it with **Node**: `node crypto.js`

Comment: Did you run it with node?

Comment: I wrote it in npm: node crypto.js stamkova.js       the output was:node : module.js:471
At line:1 char:1
+ node crypto.js stamkova.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (module.js:471:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module \projectPath\crypto.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap

Comment: It didn't find crypto

Comment: Could you run `npm ls --depth=0` in your project directory and give me the output?

Comment: MyProjectName@1.0.0 MyProject
+-- crypto@0.0.3
+-- crypto-js@3.1.9-1
`-- node.js@0.0.0

Comment: This output is really strange. Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm using visual studio Package Manager Console

Comment: Well... I assume your problem is related to this. On Linux, it is working perfectly fine...

Comment: thanks for your help, I can't move my development to linux, I try to implement encryption in javascript as part of MVC project. I appreciate your help, Have a nice day.